# Change location where jupyter notebook look for import

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have created a new environment with anaconda. Currently the environment is located at  `D:\anaconda\envs\deep-learning`

therefore I was hoping that the imports will be looked at `D:\anaconda\envs\deep-learning\Lib`

However, when I execute
`print(sys.path)`, I obtain the following result:

```
 D:\learning\deep learning computer vision\bundle 2
D:\python\python39.zip
D:\python\DLLs
D:\python\lib
D:\python

C:\Users\lemin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages
C:\Users\lemin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32
C:\Users\lemin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Users\lemin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\Pythonwin
D:\python\lib\site-packages
D:\python\lib\site-packages\win32
D:\python\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
D:\python\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\Users\lemin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\IPython\extensions
C:\Users\lemin\.ipython
```

I would like to ask what would be an easy way to change the location where my notebook is looking for import (change to `D:\anaconda\envs\deep-learning\Lib`)?

I set some PATH in the past before but I have deleted it. But it does not produce any change

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$conda activate deep-learning
$jupyter notebook
```

This should be setting your `deep-learning` env as the path for any notebooks you open inside in that session.

Comment: I have done this already but it does not work

Comment: @leMinhNguyen Have you set `PYTHONPATH` or something of that sort in your path in your system variables?

Comment: No I have made sure that isn't the case as well

Comment: Has jupyter notebook been installed separately for the environment or just for the global environment?